# boost::shared_ptr's destructor block the only thread

Tags: c++, boost, locking, shared-ptr

I'm porting a C++ program from FreeBSD to RHEL. When I test my program, I found the process will hang when call boost::shared_ptr::~shared_ptr().

I use gdb to attach the hanging process, and the stack trace is :

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00e01430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00bd8d96 in __pause_nocancel () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00bd30b2 in __pthread_mutex_lock_full () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x04a60a26 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x08069b61 in boost::detail::lightweight_mutex::scoped_lock::scoped_lock(boost::detail::lightweight_mutex&) ()
#5  0x080699d3 in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release() ()
#6  0x08069999 in boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count() ()
#7  0x08069952 in boost::shared_ptr<SS::Conf::SSConfNode>::~shared_ptr() ()
#8  0x00124fde in SS::Conf::SSConfManager::createConfFile(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /home/y/lib/libSS_conf.so.1
#9  0x00125e0c in SS::Conf::SSConfManager::createAllConfFiles() () from /home/y/lib/libSS_conf.so.1
#10 0x0012946b in SS::Conf::SSConfManager::initFromDisk(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /home/y/lib/libSS_conf.so.1
#11 0x00129c3b in SS::Conf::SSConfManager::configure(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /home/y/lib/libSS_conf.so.1
#12 0x00156d0c in SS::Init::configure() () from /home/y/lib/libSS_init.so.1
#13 0x0805ac63 in SS::Main::init() ()
#14 0x0807117e in main ()
```

And my process only contains one thread:

```
(gdb) info thread
* 1 Thread 0xf77a8a40 (LWP 16724)  0x00c54430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

When I **undef** BOOST_HAS_THREADS in header file and rebuild the program, everything goes well.

The boost version is 1.32,I'm using gcc 3.4.6-11 on RHEL4.8.

Comment: Boost 1.32 is quite old. Maybe it's good idea to try a newer version?

Comment: The error is in line 574 of the file `detect_missing_code.cc`. On a more serious node: Please post short, self contained and correct examples, otherwise people will just have to resolve to guessing. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: The origin code is in a mess, I'll try to add some self contained codes later.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what the question is, but this is likely a relevant portion from the [1.32 documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety):

> `shared_ptr` uses `Boost.Config` to detect whether the implementation supports threads. If your program is single-threaded, but your platform is autodetected by `Boost.Config` as supporting multiple threads, `#define BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS` to eliminate the thread safety overhead.

Thus, consider using `#define BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS` instead of undefining `BOOST_HAS_THREADS`.

And this is the [1.33 and beyond documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety):

> Starting with Boost release 1.33.0, `shared_ptr` uses a lock-free implementation on the following platforms:
>
> - GNU GCC on x86 or x86-64;
> - GNU GCC on IA64;
> - Metrowerks CodeWarrior on PowerPC;
> - GNU GCC on PowerPC;
> - Windows.
>
> If your program is single-threaded and does not link to any libraries that might have used shared_ptr in its default configuration, you can `#define` the macro `BOOST_SP_DISABLE_THREADS` on a project-wide basis to switch to ordinary non-atomic reference count updates.
>
> (Defining `BOOST_SP_DISABLE_THREADS` in some, but not all, translation units is technically a violation of the One Definition Rule and undefined behavior. Nevertheless, the implementation attempts to do its best to accommodate the request to use non-atomic updates in those translation units. No guarantees, though.)
>
> You can define the macro `BOOST_SP_USE_PTHREADS` to turn off the lock-free platform-specific implementation and fall back to the generic `pthread_mutex_t`-based code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the reason.
My main program build with boost 1.32, but one of my .so file build with boost 1.38. There are 2 shared_ptr implementations when running my program and caused this problem. After I rebuild my so file with boost 1.32, the program runs well.